# Testing the Class Type of a User Defined Class in Matlab

Tags: matlab, oop, binary-tree

I am building a tree class in matlab as a learning exercise.

The code is shown below.

The part where I am testing the class type of the LeftNode and RightNode is where I'm having problems.

The version below works for the first call but doesn't seem a particularly clean way to test the class type, and it doesn't work at all on the base case (which doesn't have a RightNode or LeftNode).

What is the correct way to to test the class type of a user defined class in both cases?

To Run the code just use

```
LeftNode = TreeNode(2,[],[]);
RightNode = TreeNode(2,[],[]);
TN = TreeNode(1,LeftNode, RightNode);
TN.getSum()



classdef TreeNode < handle

properties
    LeftNode  
    RightNode
    Data
end

methods

    function TN = TreeNode(Data, Left, Right)

        TN.Data = Data;
        TN.LeftNode = Left;
        TN.RightNode = Right;

    end

     function sum = getSum(this)

         sum = this.Data;

         if (class(this.LeftNode) == 'TreeNode') == 1 || isempty(this.LeftNode)                
             sum = sum + getSum(this.LeftNode);
         end

         if (class(this.RightNode) == 'TreeNode') == 1 || isempty(this.RightNode)                
            sum = sum + getSum(this.RightNode); 
         end

     end

end

end
```

Comment: a) you don't need to do if test == true. That's just superfluous. Just do if test. b) What do you expect isempty to return? have you defined an `isempty` method for your object??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best way to test for class is 'isa' function:

```
isa(this.LeftNode,'TreeNode')
```

Your method will also work if you use the correct string compare function: Dont use '==' but use 'strcmp'

```
strcmp(class(this.LeftNode),'TreeNode')
```

Anyway, go with 'isa' function.

Some other bugs to fix:

```
 if isa(this.LeftNode,'TreeNode') && ~isempty(this.LeftNode)                
     sum = sum + this.LeftNode.getSum();
 end
```